# How to handle the Wikipedia drop down list in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need help with this assignment

1. Go to https://www.wikipedia.org/
2. Perform text input in search box "apprropriate technology"
3. Wait for the ajax call to display the drop down of result
4. Return back the first suggestion

Comment: Your code trials? Errors (if any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is hard to find in the HTML, because if you click in the browser the div with id `typeahead-suggestions` is hidden again. To be able to browse the HTML and search for the element I had to:

- Open the developer tools
- Type my text
- Press F8 to pause the browser
- Open the elements tab and use search to search for the text of one of the elements.

The webdriver script would be something like this:

- Find the input (id: `searchInput`) and type a partial text
- Wait for the container with items (id: `typeahead-suggestions`)
- Get the first element with tagName A in the `typeahead-suggestions` container

[image]